# Google GCM 1 push, creates 2 notifications instead of 1

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

When i run the script to push a notification with a simple message this is what i get in my device:
(i cannot post images because of my reputation but what it displays is: 2 notifications, one with the name of my app, and one with the message)
My app is built with phonegap.
Android version 5
Phonegap version 3.7.0
I use a php script to push notifications to android devices through my server:

```
$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'test test test'

);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be lot of reasons you are getting two notifications for one message. But my take is, Please check the following:

- Send the whole message in one Bundle as "title" and "body".
- Check this PHP script to make sure that you have something similar.

  ```
  include_once './GCM.php';

  $gcm = new GCM();

  $registatoin_ids = array($regId);
  $message = array("price" => $message);

  $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

  echo $result;
  }
  ?>
  ```
- Make sure you have just one and one Broadcast receiver in your Manifest to receive the Broadcast.